Encoding problem UTF-8 in docker backend image
i try to create mysql and nodejs express image
when i run mysql and backend container and open my frontend
english text can display but if data is thai text when i use mysql2 to fetch thai text
the text will be alien language
here is example data in sql
| แผนลับดับศัตรู |
| แผนลับดับศัตรู |
| แผนลับดับศัตรู |
| แผนลับดับศัตรู |
| KonoSuba ss1
| KonoSuba ss1
as you see i can display correct thai text in mysql image i try to make api to get image and title of anime
 await pool.query('SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
    let get_image_and_title = `SELECT DISTINCT title, anime_image FROM anime`
    const image_and_title = await pool.execute(get_image_and_title)
    console.log("Retrieved titles:", image_and_title);//this is array of obj contain blob image and text in example sql i give to you "KonoSuba ss1" can display normally but "แผนลับดับศัตรู" is à¹à¸œà¸™à¸¥à¸±à¸šà¸”à¸±à¸šà¸¨à¸±à¸•à¸£à¸¹

MySQL connection configuration in nodejs is
const mysql = require('mysql2');


const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: '',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: '',
  charset: 'utf8mb4',
  collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  encoding: 'utf8mb4',
});

console.log('mysql2 pool ready')



module.exports = pool.promise(); // Export the promise-based pool

Dockerfile
FROM node:20.10.0
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .


CMD ["npm", "start"]

i try to set UTF-8 in many places but i still got alien language
What i do wrong?
or What i should check to ensure both mysql and backend is endcoding correctly

I was struggling with this myself yesterday and wrote a blog post on UTF-8 issues on MySQL.
UTF-8 issues can be hard to diagnose because there are a couple different places where UTF-8 encoding needs to be specified.
You need to look at the following:

The encoding of the database
The encoding of the table
The encoding of the column
The encoding of the database connection
OS fonts

Looking at your code it seems that you are setting the character set and collation correctly on your database connection, and it looks like you have updated your table column character set and collation correctly. The column encoding should have precedence over the table and database encoding.
Additionally, if you are using MySQL8 it should pretty much work out of the box. However, the Dockerfile you included in your question is for Node and not for MySQL, so it's not clear how your MySQL Docker container is set up (and what image you are using).
To answer your question, you can diagnose some UTF-8 issues using this SQL command, which you can run in your MySQL database to see the encoding variables.
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1             |
| character_set_connection | latin1             |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | latin1             |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3            |
| collation_connection     | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.07 sec)

The above output is from a vanilla MySQL-8 Docker image. If you want to change these settings you will need to specify a my.cnf file or set some parameters when you create the container. As per the MySQL Docker documentation.
Ideally everything should be a variant of utf8mb4, but this setup works for me (to insert and select UTF-8) characters in my database via my application.
I think the problem must be in the Docker image. You can try adjust your Dockerfile and add the following:
# Set environment variables for UTF-8 locale
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

Please let me know if that works.
